# iOS - Retrieving and saving scores of a game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I developed a small game ,  , so I manage something like this , when app lunches for the first time , it save the very first record , then after that it loads and compares the new records with the the first time record . but the problem is when user hit the record it should be saved the new record but it doesn't !!! and saves the first record again ! here is my code :

```
- (void)manageScores {
    NSLog(@"managed");

    NSString *tempScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",scoreLabel.text];
    GO.scoreNumber = [tempScore integerValue];
    GO.bestScoreNumber = [tempScore integerValue];
    GO.scores.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
    GO.bestScore.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"best:%d",GO.bestScoreNumber];


    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
        NSLog(@"app already launched");
        [GO loadBestScore];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
        NSLog(@"first time lunch ever");
        [GO saveBestScore];
    }



    if  (GO.scoreNumber > GO.bestScoreNumber) {

        //**************THIS METHOD DOESN'T WORK WHEN USER HIT THE RECORD*********/////

        [GO saveBestScore];

        //**************//        

        GO.scores.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
        GO.bestScore.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"best:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
        GO.shareScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.bestScoreNumber];

        NSLog(@"new record");

    }


    if   (GO.scoreNumber < GO.bestScoreNumber) {

        GO.scores.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
        GO.bestScore.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"best:%d",GO.bestScoreNumber];
        GO.shareScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.bestScoreNumber];

        [GO loadBestScore];

        NSLog(@"NO NEW RECORD");

    }


}
```

saving and loading scores (methods form GameOver.h/m (GO) )

```
- (void)saveBestScore {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:bestScoreNumber forKey:@"highScore"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"BEST SCORE SAVED:%i",bestScoreNumber);

}


- (void)loadBestScore {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bestScoreNumber = (int)[prefs integerForKey:@"highScore"];

}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm kind of confused... and I think you probably are too.  It's unclear what the `GO` object is... I might recommend posting several of your files to a site like `GitHub` so we can look through and make more sense of your project.  There may be a core organizational problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should save scoreNumber rather than bestScoreNumber

---

Reason:

The following code wants to save the best score because GO.ScoreNumber > Go.BestScoreNumber.

```
if  (GO.scoreNumber > GO.bestScoreNumber) {

    //**************THIS METHOD DOESN'T WORK WHEN USER HIT THE RECORD*********/////

    [GO saveBestScore];

    //**************//        

    GO.scores.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
    GO.bestScore.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"best:%d",GO.scoreNumber];
    GO.shareScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",GO.bestScoreNumber];

    NSLog(@"new record");

}
```

But in saveBestScore, it stores bestScoreNumber, which is the previous highest score number.

```
[defaults setInteger:bestScoreNumber forKey:@"highScore"];
```

Comment: So look to be the instance methods on the object he refers to as `GO` in the other snippet.

Comment: Put a break point and see whether the saveBestScore function is called.

Comment: Thanks for providing the picture. I find bestScoreNumber 712, scoreNumber 912. Maybe you save the wrong number?

Comment: @Ethan bestScoreNumber is " high score " and scoreNumber is "current score "

Comment: That's the problem. You see, your current score is bigger than your highestScore, that is why you want to save it in the first place. But when you save it, you save highestScore, where you actually want to save the current score, because it is bigger, right?

Comment: oH ! yes , I did't notice that , now works fine thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)saveBestScore
```

This method doesn't take an argument, but it should.

If you're keeping scores as `int`, you should modify it to look like this:

```
- (void)saveBestScore:(int)bestScore
```

Then, on first launch, call `saveBestScore` with an argument of `0`, just to get it initialize.  In fact, if you write `saveBestScore` method correctly, you don't really need to check whether the app has already launched ever.

```
- (void)saveBestScore:(int)bestScore {
    if (bestScore > [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
        objectForKey:@"BestScore"] intValue]); {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber 
            numberWithInt:bestScore] forKey:@"BestScore"];
    }

- (int)loadBestScore {
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BestScore] 
        intValue];
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that we should pass the number as parameter to the function rather than rely on a global number.

Comment: "doesn't work"?  May as well have not posted a comment at all.  You have to be very clear and precise with what's working and not working.  Show me how you implemented these methods and how you're using them?